# including a js file in bootstrap.js firefox for android extension

Tags: android, import, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-restartless

I'm working on a bootstrapped extension for firefox for android and I want to import a js file to the bootstap.js (like importing a component in xul extensions). The classic method of using the [chrome.manifest to use a resource alia](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript_code_modules%2FUsing#Using_chrome.manifest) is not allowed for bootstrapped extensions. I tried this code of  Erik Vold but it doesn't seem to work

```
function startup(data) AddonManager.getAddonByID(data.id, function(addon) {
// Include some utility functions
include(addon.getResourceURI("includes/scanner.js").spec);
});
```

I really appreciate some help and thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, [`content` is supported](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Chrome_Registration#Instructions_supported_in_bootstrapped_add_ons) in bootstrapped add-ons since quite some time (first in Gecko 8 and starting with Gecko 10, it will auto load manifests, IIRC).
You can load js code modules from `chrome://yourpackage/content/...` not just from resource-URIs (since Gecko 4, IIRC). So there is nothing holding you back from using mozilla-style code modules.
Also, a couple of add-ons [manually add `resource` substitutions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/JavaScript_code_modules/Using#Programmatically_adding_aliases).

The stuff that Erik wrote uses [a custom `include` function](https://github.com/voldsoftware/restartless-restart-ffext/blob/master/src/bootstrap.js#L74-L85), implemented in the corresponding bootstrap.js using `loadSubScript`. That's an option, too. This scheme was invented when it wasn't yet possible to use js code modules from bootstrapped add-ons properly, e.g. because there was no `Cu.unload` yet.

Using `content` + `Cu.import` + `Cu.unload` is likely the easiest approach.

Real world example in one of my own add-ons (Desktop + Android) (the rest of the add-on is written using a custom commonjs-style `require` loader, so don't get distracted by that).

- [`chrome.manifest`](https://github.com/nmaier/about-addons-memory/blob/master/chrome.manifest) - using `content`
- [`bootstrap.js`](https://github.com/nmaier/about-addons-memory/blob/master/bootstrap.js) - using `Cu.import` with a `content` chrome-URI.

Comment: nmaier thanks for the reply,here how I did things, and i can't figure out where i'm making the mistake (trackdetect is the id of my extension): in chrome.manifest i wrote: 
content  trackdetect         chrome/includes/ 
in the bootstrap.js: Cu.import("chrome://trackdetect/includes/scanner.js");
Thanks again.

Comment: `content something somedir` will register the contents of somedir under `chrome://something/content/`. Hence `somedir/somefile.js` will be made available as `chrome://something/content/somefile.js`. In your case: `chrome/includes/scanner.js` will be available at `chrome://trackdetect/content/scanner.js`. You might refer to the already linked docs for more information.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to reply to your answer, I did the modifications as you explained, but I get this error: 
E/GeckoConsole(22534): No chrome package registered for chrome://trackdetect/content/scanner.js
At the begining, I thought there is a problem with packaging the folder, but after unzipping a packaged extension, i found that the folder is there.So, I don't really know whats the origin of the problem, maybe import doesn't support "chrome://"?I would like to load the resource manually, but to be honest,there are parts of the (previously suggested)code that I don't understand.

Comment: Do you have your code somewhere accessible over the net, so I can have a look?

Comment: Well, I know that's totally improper and I really hate asking you this, but can I send it to you in private? because, It's not accessible over the net. And I would totally understand if you refused or the site's admins. And really sorry.

Comment: Nah, that's not a good idea. I added links to a real world example to the answer, though.

Answer (score 0):

I found this way to do it:

```
    var IncludedFile={};
    Services.scriptloader.loadSubScript(aData.resourceURI.spec + "content/fileName.js", IncludedFile);
```

Then you can access the methods like this:

```
    IncludedFile.someFunction;
```